# Closing Reader/Stream in Java

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, ioexception

In my code I have to read user input from console:

```
class Demo {
    //...some code
    public String readUserInput() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
        return userInput;
    }
}
```

On first time when I use method `readUserInput()` on Demo object everything is OK. But when I create another Demo object and call method - it throws Exception with the message

> "Stream closed"

Can anybody tell me, why I have Exception on different not equal objects? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: When you `close()` the `BufferedReader` it delegates that closing to the contained `InputStreamReader` which in turn delegates closing to the contained `InputStream`, which is `System.in` in this case, and your application only has one `System.in`. You close it, you're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
new InputStreamReader(System.in)
```

When you close your BufferedReader, it closes the InputStreamReader, which in turn closes System.in.

This is all (kind of) explained in the [contract of `Closeable`'s `.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close--), which says:

> Closes this stream **and releases any system resources associated with it**.

As a result, the second time you try and read from your `BufferedReader`, this ultimately results in data being read from `System.in`, but it is unavailable. Hence your error.

---

More generally, you handle your resources poorly. Please read about, and learn to use, the try-with-resources statement.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know, that after closing Reader, System.in will be closed too. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, the javadoc isn't really clear about it; and `System.in` being a one shot resource for the entire life of a program is quite tricky to handle...

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the reader, which close... System.in

In this case, you don't have to close the Stream.